# The effect of use_sim_time in ROS

Tags: ros, rosbag

I am trying to understand what effects does setting use_sim_time to true does specially when recording and playing a rosbag, but unfortunately the info is few and hard to understand.

I know already how to set it to true, so that is no problem.[how to do it](https://answers.ros.org/question/325667/how-to-set-use_sim_time/?answer=325681#post-id-325681)

I have done some experiments with a rosbag file I have and I noticed:

- When I do `rosplay play file.bag` , the topic `\clock` is *not* published
- When I do `rosplay play file.bag --clock` the topic `\clock` *is* published

I also have noticed that when I do `rostopic echo \clock` and I play the bag, ***many*** of the time published ***is the same!*** (what does this mean??)

And lastly I have noticed that `use_sim_time` has *no effect* on any of these results.

So what effect does setting this parameter to true have?

Answer (score 2):

- In order for a ROS node to use simulation time according to the /clock topic, the /use_sim_time parameter must be set to true before the node is initialized. In other words,
  The ROS API used to get times `ros::Time time = ros::Time::now()` will retrieve time data from the `/clock` topic rather than using the system clock. If you turn `use_sim_time` off then any time values published to `/clock` will be ignored
- If the /use_sim_time parameter is set, the ROS Time API will return time=0 until it has received a value from the /clock topic. Then, the time will only be updated on receipt of a message from the /clock topic and will stay constant between updates

More information follow: [[1]](http://wiki.ros.org/Clock#Using_Simulation_Time_from_the_.2BAC8-clock_Topic), [[2]](https://answers.ros.org/question/288672/how-use_sim_time-works/)